# Symfony serializer doesn't work with --no-dev

Tags: php, symfony, deserialization, serialization, symfony-components

I'm using symfony serializer. But if I install composer packages with `--no-dev` flag, it deserializes data that supposed to be array of objects in array of arrays instead.

This is serialization:

```
$result = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize(
    $request->getContent(),
    InputDto::class,
    'json'
);
```

And for deserialization I use annotations in DTO.

This is how "field" looks in DTO for objects array:

```
/**
 * @var OrderItemDto[]|Collection
 */
private $items = [];
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski Sorry. Forgot it :)

Comment: Also wanted to mention that this array of objects is on the third level. But I don't use any depth settings.

Comment: try after clearing your app cache

Comment: @habibun It's done on every deploy.

Comment: How does your dependencies differ between `--dev` and `--no-dev`? Is that `symfony\serializer` related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make object sublevel work you need to add to `app/config/config.yml`
in `framework` section next lines:

```
property_info:
    enabled: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code:

https://github.com/symfony/serializer/blob/master/Encoder/JsonDecode.php#L84

If you pass an option **json_decode_associative** as false

```
$result = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize(
    $request->getContent(),
    InputDto::class,
    'json',
    ['json_decode_associative' => false]
);
```

It should not try to convert it to array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. It serialized JSON object to PHP stdClass but not the type we need.